# Debugging a stored procedure in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug a Stored Procedure in Visual studio 2019. I have sysadmin rights on the server. These are the steps that I took in order to debug the stored procedure.

1. Opened the SQL Server Object explorer
2. Successfully connected to the server and opened the stored procedure
3. Right clicked on the server and enabled application debugging
4. Opened the stored procedure and put the breakpoints inside the stored procedure.
5. Started my application and when I did return `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, nothing happened, the control did not pass to the stored procedure.

I read few articles and everywhere it is saying that I need to right click on my project and open the properties window and check on "Enable SQL Server debugging". I cannot find this option in Visual Studio 2019.

I already went through this StackOverflow posts and it did not resolve my issue.

[How to debug stored procedures from a C# debug session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262244/how-to-debug-stored-procedures-from-a-c-sharp-debug-session)

Any help will be highly appreciated. I am using SQLServer2019-x64 developer edition.

Comment: Try to install [ssms tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I already have ssms, but it does not have debugging option at the top tool bar. I have 18.5.1 version of SQL server management studio.

Comment: The option is under Project Properties-->Debug, and my project is c# project. I can find the option there.